# Can I have a simple Spring Boot App on AWS Lightsail ran on public IP?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I ran my Spring Boot application on AWS Lightsail. I did it by running a docker image, how can I see endpoints from my app in public? When I type my staticIp:8080 nothing happened. Maybe I have to show it some way or maybe I can't do it with Lightsail at all?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> When I type my staticIp:8080

Your docker command uses `-p 8000:8080`, which means that you should be using port `8000` on your host, not `8080`.

You also need to make sure that instance firewall is set to allow port 8000.

Comment: Sorry I meant in web browser, mystaticIp:8080/helloworld

Comment: @MrFisherman In the browser you should use `mystaticIp:8000`, not 8080.

Answer (score 0):

You can only open port `80` for HTTP in Lightsail. I suggest you run the docker image with `-p 80:8080` which will redirect the traffic of your application through port `80`.

You will be able to access your application just with the `mystaticip` after that.